# Semantic release changelog generation doesn't follow headerPattern from config

Tags: javascript, git, frontend, semantic-release

In the project I follow this pattern for commit messages:

`feat (XX-0000): commit message`

recommended pattern is:

`feat(XX-0000): commit message`

So without space after `feat`. The problem is I'm not able to generate a proper chnagelog right now with the semantic release. I have changed the configuration to follow my pattern:

```js
plugins: [
    '@semantic-release/release-notes-generator',
    [
      '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer',
      {
        parserOpts: {
          headerPattern: /^(\w+) ?\([A-Z, a-z]+-\d+\): .+$/, /*<---------*/
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      '@semantic-release/changelog',
      {
        changelogFile: 'CHANGELOG.md',
      },
    ],
    [
      '@semantic-release/npm',
      
    ],
    [
      '@semantic-release/git'
    ],
  ],
```

As you can see here the request I've put there is correct
[image]

But the changelog is not filled with commit messages in my patter.